How to determine if an array element is initialized or not in C++?
How to determine if an array element is initialized or not in C++?
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main(void)
{
    auto arr = std::make_unique<int[]>(10);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Here I have written code using smart pointers initializing an integer array which's size is 10. Elements inside an array are not initialized. How to correctly determine if an array element is initialized or not?

How to correctly determine if an array element is initialized or not? -- It can't be done.

You can't. C++ doesn't really have a concept of "null" or "empty" values. An element will always have a value, but if it's not explicitly initialized then that value will be indeterminate. And in C++ using indeterminate values in any way leads to undefined behavior.

On a different note, it might just be your example but instead of using pointers (smart or not) and explicit allocation, use std::vector for "dynamic arrays".

So, now (after the edit) when you use make_unique correctly, the array elements will be initialized.  :-)

@Someprogrammerdude I want to create my own container class.

@АлександрАлибеков I want to create my own container class. --  So your goal was to do this: if the items are not initialized, initialize them, else leave the items alone?  If so, you would do what std::vector does and initialize the elements yourself with the type's default value (probably by simply using the {} initializer for the type).

In C++ you have to explicitly write to a variable before using it (everything else is UB). So if you didn't initalize it it isn't initialized (unless the documentation of a class like std::vector documents what it does on construction). So why do you think you need this check?

Unless you're doing a school assignment or exercise, or you have very specific requirements from your project, then the general advice is: Don't create your own container. If you really need to, then create one using one of the standard containers as base (encapsulation or composition, not inheritance).

Re: "Elements inside an array are not initialized" - Yes, they are all value initialized. Use std::make_unique_for_overwrite if you want them default initialized (holding indeterminate values in the case of int) instead.

Short response:  you can't.   Accessing the value in any way of an uninitialised int gives undefined behaviour - it is not even guaranteed that a value will be obtained and - if a value is obtained - it is indeterminate.     Once behaviour is undefined, it is not possible to reason about the behaviour of your program (or any part of it) at all.    Instead of trying to detect an uninitialised variable, prevent it being created in the first place (e.g. don't create it until the program has enough data/input to be able to initialise it or, in an array, track how many values are initialised).

You can't determine whether objects are initialized with a valid value in C++. Making sure that they have a valid value before you read them is your job as programmer.
If you need a distinguished state that indicates that the object is empty, then don't use the object type T directly, but std::optional<T> instead. An std::optional<T> can either be empty or hold an object of type T.

Without knowing your exact use case for needing to know this information, I can only speculate, but you may wish to use a map data structure rather than an array. Something like std::unordered_map<int, int>. You can then check if an "index" has been  "used" with find.
std::unordered_map<int, int> map;

map[3] = 42;

if (map.find(3) != map.end()) {
    // ...
}

